# synchronisation between prestashop site and local database

Tags: php, symfony, prestashop

How to create a script of synchronization   between a Prestashop site and a local database in php.This script allows you to retrieve simple thing as price, stock, order ... 
and display them on my webshop and vice to ca.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to access the prestashop webservices (http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Using+the+PrestaShop+Web+Service) from your php/symfony project to synchronize.

Answer (score 0):

To synchronise Prestashop stock and price from a CSV/XLS file, you can use Magicstock : http://www.prestaboutiques.fr/en/